# Blender baking textures returns black

Tags: textures, blender

I've been working in Blender for about 1.5 years now and I found a serious problem, that I cannot resolve myself. The problem is Baking textures in Cycles Render mode (actualy in every mode), which seems to bake a textures black and no shadows, colours, AO, nothing just black. Only normals and UVs bake shows something different and correct I guess. I tried many pages to make it work somehow but neither of them didn't tell me the right thing. I tried here: https://community.secondlife.com/t5/Mesh/Why-can-I-not-bake-textures-in-Blender-any-more/td-p/1603897 and here: https://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-223442.html . They somehow seem usefull but it still doesn't bake right. If you need my graphics info and Blender version: 
AMD Radeon R9 200 series
Blender 2.78
Intel core i5-3470 CPU

So these are the steps I always followed:

1. Open a new project, set up a simple cube and a sunlight
2. In edit mode unwrap that cube using Smart UV Project.
3. Add a new image 512x512 without Blank option enabled
4. The I made a new material in nodes editor (image bellow) with an Image texture node connected to the Diffuse BSDF node. I kept the imageTexture node sellected and began baking, by clicking the Bake button.
5. It didn't work so I even tried recalculating normals, making sure it's not duplicated (the object) and checking if there aren't 2 materials active.

I tried making a new project too but the probled doesn't seem to go away.

Thank you for helping!

[image: Blender cube material]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! The whole material was already black so the texture was black
I shouldn't connect that Image texture node to Diffuse BSDF yet.